# Direction Vector around Mesh's Surface

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, 3d, transform

How do I best describe the direction vector to move an object left (or right/up/down) from its current position, factoring the current view perspective into the equation?

For example, imagine the box depicted in the following picture, placed at origin (0,0,0). If I wanted to move the point on top of the box to the left, I'd have to make a step in (-1,0,0) direction (i.e. `currentPos = currentPos + Vector3.left`).

[image: Vector Left(-1,0,0) when viewing from front]

If I looked at the box from behind, I'd have to make a step in (1,0,0) direction to continue moving in the same direction.

i.e. When I'm looking at this box, placed at origin, and press an input button LEFT, I need for the point to move left and continue moving in that direction for as long as I keep pressing the button. It ultimately wraps around the surface, i.e. if I keep pressing just LEFT the point will wrap around the cube and re-appear so to speak.

[image: Vector Left(1,0,0) when viewing from behind]

Comment: If it is just cube you can use surface normals in my opinion. You can then rotate it

Comment: Cueing an object's translation from the camera's perspective can be a bit convoluted.  It's a lot easier to stick with world-space directions (`Vector3.[up,down.left,right]`) or object-local-space directions (`transform.[up,down,left,right]`).

Comment: This begs the question: what are you actually trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I want the user to be able to move a given object on the surface of e.g. a cube or a sphere in L/R/U/D directions. E.g. on pressing the left trigger, the object moves left and continues in that direction, even when behind the cube. EDIT: On second thought I'm not even sure the camera is going to help me for this at all...

Comment: When you say 'moves left', moves left of what?  Left of the camera, left of the cube or left of the world?

Comment: Left on the object, given the user's current perspective. Like if I'm looking at this cube, placed at origin, and pressing an input button LEFT, I want for the point to move Left and continue moving in that direction for as long as I keep pressing the button. It ultimately wraps around the surface, i.e. if I keep pressing just LEFT the point will wrap around the cube and re-appear so to speak.

Comment: That... doesn't make any sense to me.  Are you moving the box, or something ON the box?

Comment: I'm moving something on the box, a point, a square-shaped Sprite image actually. I've edited the original question and supplied a new picture after realizing I should've rephrased the question.

Comment: The new picture helps! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To indefinitly trace a decal around a cube:

```
private Transform Cube;
private Transform Decal;


void Update() {


    Vector3 moveLocal = Vector3.zero;

    // Set moveLocal from User Input
    moveLocal += Vector3.left * Input.GetAxis("Left"); // etc

    if (moveLocal.sqrMagnitude > 0) {

        var decalDirection = (Decal.position - Cube.position).normalized;
        var angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(Cube.forward, decalDirection, Cube.up);


        // Align decal to correct cube face
        if (angle < -135 || angle > 135) { // Rear face
            Decal.forward = -Cube.forward;
        }
        else if (angle < -45) { // Left face
            Decal.forward = -Cube.right;
        }
        else if (angle > 45) { // Right face
            Decal.forward = Cube.right;
        }
        else { // Front Face
            Decal.forward = Cube.forward;
        }

        // Now move decal in it's local space:
        Decal.Translate(moveLocal, Space.Self);
    }
}
```

Admittedly, this only rotates Left/Right, but I hope you get the idea =)

Comment: Thank you very much, while this is precisely what I'm looking for, there still seems to be an issue regarding the angles. For some reason this increases the distance between the decal and the cube though, what am I overseeing this time? :/

Comment: At a guess, probably the 'speed' that the decal is moving.  Try multiplying the `moveLocal` by some fraction (or `deltaTime`)

Comment: @AliKanat `decalDirection` is the normalized offset from Cube origin to Decal origin.

Comment: Would this work for any given other shape as well though? e.g. a sphere? I think it would as long as the angles are adjusted accordingly, right?

Comment: Also, I've tried applying `Time.deltaTime` but the decal still increases its distance to the origin continuously.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned you in my opinion you can achieve this with surface normals. I cracked some code which is not an exact solution because i used collision normals and on corners that gives different results. In any case i share it so that it gives you the idea. You can go left and right with this code relative to camera(even though it does not use anything related to camera) because it depends on surface normals.

```
private Vector3 normal;
private Vector3 contact;
private Vector3 direction;
private GameObject obj;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {
    if (obj == null)
        return;
    if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        obj.transform.position += direction * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        obj.transform.position -= direction * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Collided");

    Debug.Log("If works");
    obj = collision.gameObject;
    normal = collision.contacts[0].normal;
    contact = collision.contacts[0].point;

    //Cross product of normal and up gives direction Right. 
    //This up can be cube's up as well in cases it is tilted
    direction = (-Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, normal));

}
```

You can also see how it works from images below:

[image][image]